# Finite set of congruences

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is it true that for every $c$ there is a finite set of congruences

$a_i(mod\,\,n_i) , c = n_1<n_2<n_3<...........<n_k  \,\,\,    (1)\\
$

So that every integer satisfies at least one of the congruence (1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to [Covering Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system) of congruences. The link, and the name, will let you explore what is a quite large literature. You may also want to look at [this survey](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/covertalkunder.pdf) by Carl Pomerance.  If the $n_i$ are strictly increasing, they cannot be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: You are welcome. As you can see, it would have been hopeless to summarize!